# How do I extract the first N elements of a MONGODB collection having a particular structure in the documents

Tags: python, mongodb

Assuming I have a very nested and NON HOMOGENEOUS collections of documents how can I query the mongo database for the first N elements containing a particular structure of the data.

Imagine there are documents like:

```
doc1 = {'content':[ 'c1','c2', 'c3']}
doc2 = {'content':[ 'c1','c6', 'c6', eventMetadata:{date:'2002','jobnr':121212}]}
doc3 = {'content':[ 'c1','c9', 'c3','c7']}
doc4 = {'content':[ 'c1','c6', 'c6', eventMetadata:{date:'2003','jobnr':123331212}]}
...etc...
```

I would like the first N documents of the collection containing eventMetadata and jobnr:

pseudocode:

```
query = {eventMetadata.jobnr:'*'}
cur = enrichments_collection.find(query).limit(20)
```

EDIT 1:
[image]

Comment: try `$exists` operator `{eventMetadata.jobnr:{ $exists: true }}`

Comment: I tried but I am dong something wrong because I get an error. ( I added screenshot in question)

Comment: i think wrap it in single quotes `'$exists': true`.

Comment: It works. If you propose an answer I will acept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{eventMetadata.jobnr:{ '$exists': True }}